# SCIPsolve fails for the simple optimization program

Tags: scip

I'm trying to solve simple optimization problem using SCIP but the method SCIPsolve returns exception.

The problem is: Minimize x + y + z
subject to: x*y*z = 1 where x, y and z are integers

The source code is given below. Does anybody have idea what's wrong with this code?

I tried this code in Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. I used the latest version of SCIP source code and libraries from http://scip.zib.de/

```
//  1. Initializing the SCIP environment
SCIP* scip;
SCIP_CALL(SCIPcreate(&scip));

//  2. Load all desired plugins 
SCIP_CALL(SCIPincludeDefaultPlugins(scip));

//  3. Creating a problem 
SCIP_CALL(SCIPcreateProb(scip, "Example", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL));

//  4. Creating variables 
SCIP_VAR *x, *y, *z;
SCIP_CALL(SCIPcreateVar(scip, &x, "x", -1, 1, 1.0, SCIP_VARTYPE_INTEGER, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL));
SCIP_CALL(SCIPcreateVar(scip, &y, "y", -1, 1, 1.0, SCIP_VARTYPE_INTEGER, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL));
SCIP_CALL(SCIPcreateVar(scip, &z, "z", -1, 1, 1.0, SCIP_VARTYPE_INTEGER, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL));

//  5. Creating constraint
SCIP_EXPR* exprx;
SCIP_EXPR* expry;
SCIP_EXPR* exprz;

SCIP_CALL(SCIPexprCreate(SCIPblkmem(scip), &exprx, SCIP_EXPR_VARIDX, 0));
SCIP_CALL(SCIPexprCreate(SCIPblkmem(scip), &expry, SCIP_EXPR_VARIDX, 1));
SCIP_CALL(SCIPexprCreate(SCIPblkmem(scip), &exprz, SCIP_EXPR_VARIDX, 2));

/* setup monomial for x*y*z */
SCIP_Real exponents[3] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
SCIP_EXPRDATA_MONOMIAL* monomial;
SCIP_Real one = 1.0;
SCIP_CALL(SCIPexprCreateMonomial(SCIPblkmem(scip), &monomial, one, 3, NULL, exponents));

/* create polynomial expression x*y*z */
SCIP_EXPR* expr;
SCIP_EXPR* children[3] = {exprx, expry, exprz};
SCIP_CALL(SCIPexprCreatePolynomial(SCIPblkmem(scip), &expr, 3, children, 1, &monomial, 0.0, FALSE));

/* setup expression tree with expr as root expression, the tree is defined w.r.t. 3 variables */
SCIP_EXPRTREE* exprtree;
SCIP_CALL(SCIPexprtreeCreate(SCIPblkmem(scip), &exprtree, expr, 3, 0, NULL));

/* assign SCIP variables to tree */
SCIP_VAR* vars[3] = { x, y, z };
SCIP_CALL(SCIPexprtreeSetVars(exprtree, 3, vars));

/* create and add nonlinear constraint x*y*z = 1 */
SCIP_CONS* constraint;
SCIP_CALL(SCIPcreateConsBasicNonlinear(scip, &constraint, "xyz", 0, NULL, NULL, 1, &exprtree, &one, 1.0, 1.0));
SCIP_CALL(SCIPaddCons(scip, constraint));

//  6. Solving the problem
SCIP_CALL(SCIPsolve(scip));
```

Comment: Please mention the thrown exception in future questions like this. You must not expect people to compile and debug your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Step 4, you miss the addition of the variables to SCIP (SCIPaddVar).

Comment: That's it, it solves the problem. Thank you very much!